# How to identify a NDB on a garmin 430W or GTN650?

Tags: helicopter, ifr-navigation, inertial-nav-system, navaids, ndb

I have a Garmin 430W and a GTN 650 interfaced with a G500H in my aircraft. I can program either to go direct to an NDB. The question comes as to whether or not I can identify the navaid. Reading through the manuals I cannot determine how I would do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about the GTN 650 but the 430W has no ability to receive NDB signals, so at least you won't be able to identify the navaid using that equipment.

Comment: So when I put in “direct to “ to an NDB that is essentially a gps fix?

Comment: Yes it's just a GPS waypoint.

Answer (score -1):

On the GTN 650, you can go to the waypoints page and enter the name of the NDB. It will now show distance and bearing to the NDB from your current position. See pg.180 in the GTN 650 manual. Hope this helps!

Comment: Question already says that programming the course is possible.  You haven't answered the question, which is *how to confirm reaching the navaid*.

Comment: I did answer it. It shows distance and bearing. When you reach the navaid the distance will be 0NM and the bearing will swing to the opposite direction you have been flying on similar to a VOR cdi but the whole needle will swing for NDB. It will do this both on the GTN650 and on your PFD (blue needles) if they are connected. In your question, you are referring to it more on a GPS level programming into your flight plan/direct but the way I am saying shows it more like a real NDB (generated by your GPS). Pg. 180 explains it well.

Comment: It won't identify the navaid, just the _place where it believes the navaid to be_.  I think that Wes is looking for physical confirmation, but perhaps I'm mistaken about that?  The question could certainly benefit from more clarity.

Comment: Yes maybe some more clarification but if your aircraft cannot receive NDB signals you cannot directly connect to the NDB (obviously). The way I (and the manual) mention it is GPS in lieu of NDB. This is by using the NDB in the GPS database (if it is available which most likely is). This is similar to using GPS in lieu of DME on approaches. This is a legal way to identify the Navaid, we do this all the time in approaches using GPS in lieu.

Comment: Taylor B thank you for that! I believe that is why I cannot identify it is because it is essentially an GPS waypoint in lieu of an NDB. Thank you for that clarification!

Comment: Of course! Glad it helped!